# Excepcion: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Ucanaccess nombre de columna duplicada en la tabla derivada

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans-8.2, jdbc, ms-access-2007

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una sentencia SQL en Java, pero al momento de ejecutarla se genera la siguiente excepción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la sentencia SQL que estoy ejecutando desde Java NetBeans:

```
select * , iif(campo=0, 'No', 'Si') as Determinar from Tabla
```

Hay alguna solución?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba cambiar el nombre de `Determinar` a algo como `qwert`.

Comment: Sal. Intente cambiar el nombre y aun me pone la misma excepción